# Resume notification playback controls?

Tags: android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

So I want to be able to resume notifications in my app like Spotify. So Spotify you can start playback then go to phone settings and turn off notifications for Spotify. The notification is gone, then re-enable the notifications. The notification is back.

Is there a callback or a category for these zombie notifications?

Right now I use `.setCategory(CATEGORY_SERVICE)` in my notification builder but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use CATEGORY_TRANSPORT the notification will come back after being turned off